# Understanding deeply using a specific case how makefiles are interpreted

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to understand deeply how makefiles work.

For example, I've the following one:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I.
DEPS = int_array.h
OBJS = int_array.o test_int_array.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)


test_int_array: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)


clean:
    rm -rf *.o test_int_array *.dSYM
```

The part that I really don't understand fully is :

```
...

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)


test_int_array: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

...
```

I know that the option `-c` basically indicates just to run the preprocessor, compiling and assembling steps (i.e. without producing executables, I guess).

`-o` means to write the output to the specified file. Which file in this case?

I understood that `$@` (and `$^` for right) is apparently referring to a "left" side, but which one? Is it referring, in the first case, to the left side of `:`, that is `%.o`?

What does `$<` mean?

Could you please explain step by step how the make tool would interpret those two statements?

I think I understood this part more or less:

```
...
test_int_array: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

...
```

which should mean produce an executable called "test_int_array" (which basically is indicated by these options `-o $@` from the `$(OBJS)` files on the right (stated using the option `$^`).

Is `$(CFLAGS)` needed in both cases? Does the order matter?

Comment: Yes - `make` (as well as `makefiles`) are a syn. of `makefile` - no need to bicker over the tag here :)

Comment: @JonClements The edit sequence was actually because of the tag `c`. Does the tag `c` apply to this question?

Comment: @2501 Okay - doesn't strike me as useful here... so imho it can be left out...

Comment: @JonClements Why the comments were removed?

Comment: Like every Unix command, `make` comes with a [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), and you can find the answers to your questions in there.

Comment: Have your questions been asked? If so could you select an answer please? If not, I'd be glad to provide more information if you tell me what's missing :)

Comment: @sokkyoku I can't accept 2 answers, and both have given me good info, that's why I didn't accept. It would be unfair for one of you if I accepted one and not the other...but actually I'm going to accept yours since you have les reputation ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Makefile, each rule follows this format:

```
resulting_file : source_files
  steps to get resulting_file from source_files
```

What is called respectively lefthand and righthand in a rule is the resulting_file and the source_files.

---

`%.ext : %.ext2`

is a pattern rule. It allows your Makefile to automatically create any `.ext` file it needs if it can find a file at the same path with `.ext2`.

`%.c : %.o`

is a pattern rule to obtain your `.o` files (int_array.o test_int_array.o) from their equivalent `.c` files (int_array.c test_int_array.c)

This is invoked when you specify that `$(OBJS)` is needed to build the `test_int_array` file.

Pattern rules automatically use certain variables, such as `$(CFLAGS)` so you do not need to manually add it in that rule. You can find a full list of implicitly used variables in pattern rules here: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html#SEC96

---

You can find out about `$@`, `$<` and `$^` and similar here: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html#SEC101

`$@`: the entire lefthand

`$<`: the first file in the righthand

`$^`: the entire righthand list of files, space separated.

Answer (score 3):

In the example:

```
test_int_array: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

`$@` is the filename of the target for this rule: `test_int_array`.

`$^` is the names of all prerequisites.
This would be whatever is contained in `OBJS`, so: `int_array.o test_int_array.o`

---

In the example:

```
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

`$<` is the name of the first prerequisite: `%.c`

`$@` is the filename of the target for this rule: `%.o`

---

$(CFLAGS) is not needed for linking, since it only includes the flag `-I`. Also the CFLAGS indicates that the flags are used for compiling only, hence C *FLAGS*.

Comment: By prerequisite you mean what's specified on the right side of the `:`?